# Como puedo generar un numero entero random con una longitud establecida

Tags: flutter, dart

Quiero generar el string de un número entero que sea aleatorio con una longitud establecida, es decir, si el número de la longitud es 5 generar un número random de 5 dígitos (10000 - 99999). ¿Hay algún método o paquete para lograr lo que necesito? agradecería cualquier ayuda

Comment: Ese rango es de solo 2 números, el 99999 y el 100000. ¿No será de 10000 a 99999?

Comment: Toda la razón, ya corrijo, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de revisar las respuestas a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13318207/13419694) de Stackoverflow en inglés y al parecer solo cuentas con la posibilidad de generar un número aleatorio entre 0 (incluido) y un máximo (excluido) con la función `nextInt` de la clase [`Random`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.4/dart-math/Random-class.html).

Por lo tanto, puedes lograr lo que quieres con algunas operaciones matemáticas:

```
int aleatorio(int min, int max)
    return Random().nextint(max - min) + min;
}
```

De hecho, la documentación sugiere lo mismo solo que para generar un número mayor o igual a 50 y menor que 150:

```
intValue = Random().nextInt(100) + 50
```

---

Si quieres que el máximo esté incluido solo tienes que sumarle 1 al parámetro:

```
int aleatorio2(int min, int max)
    return Random().nextint(max - min + 1) + min;
}
```

Entonces, para generar un número de 5 dígitos solo tienes que llamar a la primera función así:

```
var n = aleatorio(10000, 100000);
```

O la segunda así:

```
var n = aleatorio(10000, 99999);
```

Comment: Hola Mateo, agradezco tu respuesta, pero la solución que me brindaste, si bien es útil, es poco practica para lo que quiero lograr

Comment: @alvarezmiguelcl con un poco de imaginación puedes adaptarlo a lo que necesites. Pero bueno, si necesitabas un `string` podrías haber empezado por ahí.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, plantee mal la pregunta, te pido disculpas.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré el paquete [random_string](https://pub.dev/packages/random_string) el cual proporciona el método randomNumeric(), que como parámetro se proporciona la longitud del numero aleatorio a generar y funciona perfecto para lo que necesitaba.